# Generate sequence diagram not from running code

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

is there an option to generate sequence diagram from not running code in enterprise architect ? I know it is possible from running code but my code is just a library and not able to run it. Thanks. I have all .cs files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. To auto-generate a sequence diagram, you have to run the code and record its execution in EA's execution analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tool that is called [phpcallgraph](http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/) for PHP5 coding. You can generate call graphs without executing your code and there is an option to create sequence diagram using UMLGraph and GNU plotutils.

Comment: Please provide links to the tool you're talking about.